# Add ViewPger inside a ParallaxScrollingView

Tags: android, android-viewpager, parallax, android-scrollview

Hi I am using ParallaxScrollView for Parallax effect but ViewPager is not getting parallax effect which is used inside scrollview.
Can any one help on this or give an idea. Have used a normal ViewPager inside a scrollview.

```
 <com.nirhart.parallaxscroll.views.ParallaxScrollView
    android:id="@+id/vde_mv_scroll_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:inner_parallax_factor="1.9"
    app:parallax_factor="1.9"
    app:parallax_views_num="1">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/white">

        <include
            android:id="@+id/inc_gallery"
            layout="@layout/proj_galery_new"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            />
        <include
            android:id="@+id/inc_unit"
            layout="@layout/unit_layout"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/inc_gallery"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/Margin_0" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</com.nirhart.parallaxscroll.views.ParallaxScrollView>
```

In the above unit_layout.xml uses ViewPager. which does not have a ParallaxScrollViewEffect

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the RelativeLayout. Parallax recognizes the first tag to be the one which will be hidden during the effect. The succeeding views are viewed on top.

```
<com.nirhart.parallaxscroll.views.ParallaxScrollView
android:id="@+id/vde_mv_scroll_view"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
app:inner_parallax_factor="1.9"
app:parallax_factor="1.9"
app:parallax_views_num="1">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/inc_gallery"
        layout="@layout/proj_galery_new"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />
    <include
        android:id="@+id/inc_unit"
        layout="@layout/unit_layout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/inc_gallery"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/Margin_0" />

</com.nirhart.parallaxscroll.views.ParallaxScrollView>
```

Comment: @Shechan then how to show layout_below . Will it Scrollview recognize layout in vertical like in linearlayout ?

Comment: I don't comprehend your question, but to summarize.. In my code the first include is the one hiding.. the next include is on top.

Comment: If your second tag is a linear layout you may add views normally in it like you said

Comment: To make it clearer.. assume the <ParallaxScrollView> will accept two tags either layout or view. THerefore it will look like this on most cases <ParallaxScrollView><TheHiddenVieworLayout></TheHiddenVieworLayout><TheShownVieworLayout></TheShownVieworLayout></ParallaxScrollView>

Comment: Ok thanx but If I have 10 layouts included  (i.e., more than 2 layouts ) then how to show a Parallax ScrollView among which there is also a ViewPager as 1 item @Sheychan

Comment: Then firstly leave the first layout as it is, next put the 9 layouts inside a single layout.. this layout contains 9 layouts which will be seen on top of the first layout. got it?

Comment: but which layout must be inside ParallaxScrollView. Also is it possible to put ParallaxScrollView for a particular layout inside this Scroll

Comment: Yah like I said any LAYOUT or VIEW As long as it is the first layout which is inside the Parallax ScrollView, then it is hidden, the next one will be the shown when scrolling